# How can a google app notify an offline user (besides sending email)?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

I´d like to send notifications to my app users, even if they are offline, such as "you have a new task, click here to evaluate". I COULD send an email, but besides that ancient solution, is it possible to send a visible notification to a google plus user, using its offline token or some other fancy technique?

For instance, I can create a Moment, but it is stored at an obscure menu inside google plus called application log. No one will even notice a "Moment" there. If I could configure a Moment to appear in an alert box, that would solve the problem.

At the other hand, a google app cannot write at the user stream without the user hitting a button. That makes even less sense, because the user will not push a button to notify himself... Besides, the notification is for the user, not for any of his circles. I don´t need to publish at the stream (but that would be better than nothing).

Currently my environment is the web.

This is probably a newbie question, but I could not find any answer around.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have some kind of app running on the user's device. You say "currently my environment is the web", so I assume that you're not developping a native IOS/Android app.

You could build a Chrome App / Firefox extension / Windows app to fetch and display the notifications to the user.

Comment: that´s what I'm afraid of... this is not an option for us. We rather stay with emailing.